# begin and end overloads for istream_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, iterator

I wrote this pretty straight forward begin and end overloads for `istream_iterator`.

Is this standards compliant? Any problems with usage?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

namespace std
{

    template <typename T>
    std::istream_iterator<T> begin(std::istream_iterator<T> iter)
    {
        return iter;
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::istream_iterator<T> end(std::istream_iterator<T>)
    {
        return std::istream_iterator<T>();
    }

}

int main()
{
    for (std::string s : std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin))
    {
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would give it the benefit of the doubt. @user84832, could you please add some clarification as to what exactly you would like reviewed about your code?

Comment: I see this as a code review. Nice little utility class (I have something similar in my toolbox).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that's how I would have written in.
Its not normal to call `std::begin()` and `std::end()` on an iterator.

I would have arranged for a some type to represent the stream as a container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    template<typename T>
    struct StreamAsContainer
    {
        std::istream& str;
        StreamAsContainer(std::istream& str) : str(str) {}
    };

    template <typename T>
    std::istream_iterator<T> begin(StreamAsContainer<T>& c)
    {
        return std::istream_iterator<T>(c.str);
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::istream_iterator<T> end(StreamAsContainer<T>&)
    {
        return std::istream_iterator<T>();
    }

}

int main()
{
    namespace TA=ThorsAnvil;
    for (std::string s : TA::StreamAsContainer<std::string>(std::cin))
    {
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this standards compliant? Any problems with usage?

No it's not standards compliant. From [namespace.std]:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a
>   namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
>   for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
>   and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.

You're adding a declaration to namespace `std` which does not fall into any of the "otherwise specified" categories (e.g. you're not specializing a template based with a user-defined type). What you are doing is **undefined behavior**.

---

To avoid that, you could just wrap the `istream` in a user-defined container:

```
template <typename T>
struct istream_range
{
    std::istream& stream;
    std::istream_iterator<T> begin() { return {stream}; }
    std::istream_iterator<T> end() { return {}; }
};

for (std::string s : istream_range<std::string>{std::cin})
{
    std::cout << s;
}
```

---

In Eric Niebler's [range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), he introduced a way to make an istream range to solve the same problem, but actually introduces different types for the iterator and the sentinel. There, you could also do:

```
#include <range/v3/istream_range.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp>

ranges::for_each(
    ranges::istream<std::string>(std::cin),
    [](std::string const& s){
        std::cout << s;
    });
```

Comment: I would have done the same as you with the `istream_range` with begin/end as methods. But I was unsure on the requirements of container like object and what they need to support for `std::begin()` and `std::end()` to work correctly. Do you have any incite on using this (admittedly nicer) technique over the free standing functions I use in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Serious problem:

As an user of the language [you're not supposed to extend the Standard namespace at will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683794/bad-practice-to-declare-names-in-the-standard-namespace). This makes your code not portable and very fragile. If the Standard Library adds such functionality at some point, your code will likely break.

---

A very tiny thing, but here:

> ```
> for (std::string s : std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin))
> ```

Is a place where you can and should be using `auto`. We can see that this piece of code repeats itself by specifying the type `std::string` twice, thus it should be DRYed up:

```
for (auto s : std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin))
```